# Make iPhone silent while sleeping

Tags: iphone

When I go to sleep I tell a smart alarm app (Pillow) that I'm going to sleep. When I wake up I tell that same app that I'm awake. Between these two events, I would like for my iPhone not to vibrate or make any other noise. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm looking for a way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 3):

A partial solution is to create an "Automation" with the "Shortcuts" app that enters Do-not-disturb mode whenever the smart-alarm app is opened. Then one has to manually exit Do-not-disturb mode every morning upon waking up. Not a perfect solution by any means, but I think it's probably good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings and scroll down about 1 page. You'll see an option that reads "Do not  Disturb". Turn this on and it silences your phone.

Comment: You aren't answering the question, but there's a faster way to enable DnD. Summon Control Center from anywhere and the Do Not Disturb toggle is right there (the moon icon)

Answer (score 1):

Like jmh said, that is a valid option too. But, if you don't want to have to open settings, you can access Control Center and tap on the 'moon' icon to activate Do Not Disturb.

How do I access Control Center? Steps:

- iPhone without a home button: swipe down from the top right of the screen.
- iPhone with a home button: swipe up from the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Airplane mode as well brother and turning off your wifi as well, its far better for your health and your sleep not to have a device emitting radiation next to your head.

Comment: Would you be able to edit in which radiation you are concerned with and at which distance you consider it safe? I’m curios if your co cern is blue light radiation or [SAR values](https://www.apple.com/legal/rfexposure/iphone12,3/en/) or something else.